# Is it possible for Dialogflow to train the agent on each query?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I wonder if it is possible for Dialogflow to train the agent on each query depending on a response for correctly detected intents?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do this, since there's no way to determine if a query was matched correctly without a human making the decision.

Comment: Then i cannot give feedback for the intent labels when i am running tests. Okay Thank you Dan Imrie-Situnayake.